# How can I create an accurate parallax scene?

Tags: ios, uiview, parallax

I created an extension of the UIView class in order to implement the parallax effect throughout my entire project. I would advice you to do the same, it's so much easier.

```
#pragma mark - Handling Effects

- (void)setMotion:(CGFloat)motion
{
    if (motion == 0) {

        for (UIMotionEffect *motionEffect in self.motionEffects) {

            [self removeMotionEffect:motionEffect];
        }
    }
    else {

        UIInterpolatingMotionEffect *horizontalEffect = [[UIInterpolatingMotionEffect alloc] initWithKeyPath:@"center.x" type:UIInterpolatingMotionEffectTypeTiltAlongHorizontalAxis];
        horizontalEffect.minimumRelativeValue = @(motion);
        horizontalEffect.maximumRelativeValue = @(-motion);

        UIInterpolatingMotionEffect *verticalEffect = [[UIInterpolatingMotionEffect alloc] initWithKeyPath:@"center.y" type:UIInterpolatingMotionEffectTypeTiltAlongVerticalAxis];
        verticalEffect.minimumRelativeValue = @(motion);
        verticalEffect.maximumRelativeValue = @(-motion);

        [self addMotionEffect:horizontalEffect];
        [self addMotionEffect:verticalEffect];
    }
}

- (CGFloat)motion
{
    if (self.motionEffects.count == 0) {

        return 0;
    }
    else {

        UIInterpolatingMotionEffect *horizontalEffect = (UIInterpolatingMotionEffect *)[self.motionEffects objectAtIndex:0];

        return [horizontalEffect.minimumRelativeValue floatValue];
    }
}
```

Example:

```
view1.motion = 10;
view2.motion = 15;
view3.motion = 20;
```

The problem is that the effect is not quite accurate. Yes, it looks like parallax but I don't get the strong feeling that I'm emerged in a 3D scenery. The views slide a bit more to left or a bit more to the right.

Is there anyway, I can calculate the parallax motion (.motion) of a UIView based on it's size?
I'm guessing angular sizes, and view points but I have no idea how those are measured...

Answer (score 0):

This equation describes the size of objects relative to the distance they are placed at:

```
angularSize = realSize / distance;
```

By implementing your own initialization method:

```
- (instancetype)initWithRealSize:(CGSize)realSize;
```

You can change the size of the view by adjusting it's distance.

The motion value can be calculated as follows:

```
horizontalMotion = angularSize.width / 10.0;

verticalMotion = angularSize.height / 10.0;
```